# Is it possible in CSS to select an element specifically without an ID or class?

Tags: html, css

I am making a theme for a website, but I ran into a problem. I can't change their HTML or use javascript, only CSS.

This is what the site's HTML looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="margin:a ridiculously massive number">
    <p id="title"> Title of page </p>
    <p> Words that cannot be read because of the ridiculous margin </p>
  </div>
  <div id="otherContent"> There a lot of divs without ridiculous margin all with different ids </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the ridculous margin without affecting the other divs margins. Is this possible?

Comment: `.container > div:not(#otherContent)`?

Comment: [style='margin:a ridiculously massive number'] { margin:0!important; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can target the `div` that is the `first-child` inside of `.container` as to not effect other `div`s.

```
.container div:first-child{
   //code
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/udwyozk5/)

Example 1 is specifically for the example you posted where the div you would like to target is the first child of it's parent. Also note if the `margin` is inline like your example you're going to have to over-ride it with `!important` like so:

```
.container div:first-child{
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

**OR**

You could also use the `:not` selector if the other's have a similar class

```
.container div:not(.classname) {
   //code
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/udwyozk5/2/)

The point of example 2 is if your `div` isn't the first child and the only without a `class` (it would probably be unlikely you would have multiple `div`s with the same classname except one but it's possible). in your example you could also use `:not()` to target that other div with id `#otherContent` like so:

```
.container div:not(#otherContent) {
   //code
}
```

**OR**

The last option you can use if the others don't apply would be `nth-of-type()` to target specifically which one you want to effect:

```
.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
   //code
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/udwyozk5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will have to use `first-child` selector with `!important` keyword, as this is the only way to make rule more specific than `style="margin"` rule:

```
.container > div:first-child {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the other divs have ID you can use the following:

```
div>div:not([id]) {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```